# What is an easy algorithm to introduce positive correlation?

Tags: correlation

Suppose I have a sorted list of 30 numbers with display exponential trend (a few numbers are fairly large, and a lot of them are relatively small).

Now I am selecting a random index (a realization from DISCRETE-UNIFORM(0, 29)) and remove that entry from the list.

Now, my goal is that the next number I remove from the list should be similar in magnitude to the last draw (thus introducing positive correlation between consecutive draws).

Of course, once the list shrinks to 1, there is only one option left, irrespective or the correlation.

It would be nice if this function could take in a correlation coefficient R that the caller can change from 0 (completely independent) to 1 (always pick the next closest value).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly: how would you calculate a correlation between only one tupel (two consecutive values)?

Comment: Maybe the way lag-1 correlation is computed in a time series

Comment: So you mean the series of removed values should be correlated with the same series shifted by 1 equal to a pre-specified value?

Comment: It doesn't have to be rigorous. I could also design the algorithm for replacement (just drawing from the identically distributed distribution each time). I just need a simple algorithm that gives me similar values as the ones before (with some probability).

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/ it looks like p*previousRealization +(1-p^2)*nextRealization works when the realizations are iid.

Comment: What does your formula mean? It clearly is neither a probability nor one of your 30 numbers, so it is not apparent how it could be used to answer your question.